# How to count how many objects will be returned by an ObjectQuery<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building an ObjectQuery like this:

```
        string query = "select value obj from Entities.Class as obj " +
                       "where obj.Property = @Value";

        ObjectQuery<Class> oQuery = new ObjectQuery<Class>(query, EntityContext.Instance);
        oQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Value", someVariable));
```

I can now assign this object as a DataSource for a control, or iterate with a foreach loop or even force a materialization to a List, however, I can I count the number of objects that will be returned, without forcing a materialization?

Do I need to create a companion query that will execute a count() or is there a function that will do that for me somewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectQuery<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`, so can't you simply use the extension method:

```
int count = oQuery.Count();
```

What happens if you execute this? I would have expected the overall query to just do a Count()... (not that I've done much EF...).

Comment: This worked for me, but I had a heck of a time exposing the Count() method. If anyone runs into a situation where ObjectQuery.Count() isn't available, don't forget to include using System.Linq to the class. This got me stuck for a while as I'd removed unused using statements earlier and my Intellisense options for my ObjectQuery object were a subset of what's available.

Answer (score 1):

The ObjectQuery<T> class implements the IEnumerable<T> interface, which supports the Count() method.

What do you get from this?

```
int count = oQuery.Count();
```

Comment: Note that Enumerable.Count() *will* force the data to load; you'd need Queryable.Count() to get the composable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If the count is lower than 1 then it has found a new record, if not, it already has that record.